# EmailQueue not sending mail: "cannot find the path specified" in Windows

Tags: php, windows, smtp, phpmailer, mail-queue

I am using the emailqueue by lorenzoherrera,
I have installed the setup in the windows 7 and executed the script and getting the error

```
The system cannot find the path specified 
PHPMailer error : <strong> Could not execute : /var/qmail/bin/sendmail </strong>
```

This seems the linux path setting, what, how and where do I have to modify for windows setting, I am having no idea what to do.

Tough the db is showing the mail as send.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For it to even be looking at that path means it's being told to send via qmail, which you won't have on Windows. You need to alter the code that calls PHPMailer so that it's told to send either via a local mail server (using `isMail()`), or directly via SMTP using `isSMTP()`, along with appropriate login credentials. It sounds like this is a misconfiguration in EmailQueue, so I suggest you contact them for support - PHPMailer is only doing what it's told.

Comment: PHPMailer defaults to `/var/qmail/bin/qmail-inject` for the qmail path, so they must be setting it in their script or in `sendmail_path` in their php.ini. If it's really using `isSMTP`, it would never have a reason to even look at the sendmail path.

Comment: I don't know by default it is using sendmail $mail->IsSMTP() is displaying 'sendmailer' when I tried to run the independent application it uses the mail.  Any idea how to change this ..

Comment: I have uncommented the sendmail path in php.ini, do we need to change in class.phpmailer.php as well ?